# Prove that a set is orthonormal on $L_2$

Tags: lp-spaces, orthonormal

I would like to prove that the set of elements:

\begin{equation}
A_n(t)=\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{int}\right\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}
\end{equation}

is an infinite orthonormal set, on space $L_2[-\pi, \pi]$.

Which inner product should I use and which norm to prove the orthonormality?

Comment: The standard norm in $L^2 $ and the standard inner product of $L^2$, of course. $(a,b)_{L^2} = \int a(x)b(x)dx$.

Comment: ...with limits of integration $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

Comment: I know maybe it is an easy question, but how should I proceed with it? Which are the $a$ and $b$ elements that I will use within the integral? Perhaps $a=(1/ \sqrt{\pi})e^{int}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $b=(1/ \sqrt{\pi})e^{imt}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$? Sorry for all these, but I am new to this field.

Comment: @ Dr. MV: Yeap sorry, it is 0.93€\sqrt{2\pi}$

Comment: Please let me know how can I improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner product is

$$<\phi_n,\phi^*_m>=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}e^{int}\right)\,\,\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}e^{-imt}\right)\,dt$$

which equals $0$ for $m \ne m$ and $1$ for $m=n$.

Comment: So the inner product is not $(a,b)=\int a(x)b(x)dx $ but $(a,b)=\int a(x) \bar{b(x)}dx$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  There should be  complex conjugate on one of the two functions.

Comment: Ok, but what about the norm? I still have to prove that $||A_n(t)||=1$, right?

Comment: The norm is $<\phi_n,\phi^*_n>=1$ as stated in the answer.